# How to use Zend Framework 2 class in my project?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I juste want to have the possibility to use the class of this library but after 2 hours impossible :

So how to use the Zend Framework 2.1 with his autoloader to just use class of this library and not create a ZF project?

I have try everything with the classmap_generator, inlude_path... i haven't any error but it still return me :

Could not find action class? Could not find version class!

Thanks you.

Comment: consider using this http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html, and also show some code where some error can be seen/traced

Comment: I don't want an entire Zend Framework project, but only use theses class.

Answer (score 3):

You can install individual Zend Framework modules via composer, which will take care of most of this for you:

composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zend-http": "2.*"
    },  
    "repositories": [
        {   
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://packages.zendframework.com/"
        }   
    ],  
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

this should take care of any autlloading for you. Composer would generate an autoloader which you would just include in your app:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

there's a load of composer examples out there:

https://packages.zendframework.com/#composer

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/easy-package-management-with-composer/

Answer (score 2):

Since ZF2 components are decoupled and focused on a specific task, one class often uses another to do its business. Simply including a single class file is usually not sufficient.

As a result, ZF2 definitely requires some autoloading. But you don't have to use the ZF2 autoloader.

If you have no autoloading already in place in your app, then it's actually pretty easy to add:

1. Make sure the path to the Zend library is on your `include_path`.
2. Register a standard PSR-0-compliant autoloader using `spl_autoload_register()`

Something like:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class)){
    $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php';
    $resolvedFile = stream_resolve_include_path($file);
    if (file_exists($resolvedFile)) {
        include $resolvedFile;
        return $class;
    }
});
```

If you already have an autoloader for your application, then I'd be quite surprised if it was not PSR-0-compliant. As before, make sure that the Zend library is on the `include_path`.

Even if the Zend library is not on your include path, you can create a custom autoloader that is aware of where in your filesystem the library is based.

In all cases, usage of the desired class is then:

```
$myinstance = new \Zend\Component\Class();
```

With the correct autoloading in place - however you choose to go about it - this class can use any other Zend classes that it needs to go about its business.

Answer (score 1):

After many search, i have install composer. But i'm not very happy of this solution cause it touch my system.

Here is my procedure, i still say that ZF documentation is very poor.

***Install ZEND FRAMEWORK WITH COMPOSER***

**1)    Allow whitelist**

suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar
In file : nano /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/suhosin.ini

**2)    Download of composer**

Apt-get install curl
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

**3)    Move composer**

mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

**4)    Copy the composer.json**

Copy composer.json (From zend framework archive) a my root folder application

**5)    Composer install**

Execute  where the composer.json is

Now you will have a folder named "vendor" in your app folder, to use in your php code :

```
include("vendor/autoload.php");
new Zend\Mail\Storage\Pop3(...);
```

And now it work for me.

**Bug allowed memory size :**

php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
change to 1024M
nano /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart

**Failed to clone http://github.com/zendframework/Component_ZendStdlib.git, git was not found,**

Install GIT
Apt-get install git

Answer (score 0):

Just register the namespace in your autoloader.

if you are using composer then add `include_once '<path to vendor dir>/autoload.php';` on top of your php file

Comment: It's too much complicated, there isn't any way to only unzip the "Zend" folder and then tell by php with this script to get class in the right folder like in the example : require_once __DIR__ . '/../library/Zend/Loader/ClassMapAutoloader.php';
$loader = new Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader();
$loader->registerAutoloadMap(__DIR__ . '/../library/Zend/.classmap.php');
$loader->register();

Comment: The most simple is include that class in your script (and any needed dependency) Sometimes I do this for quick tests (include_once Zend/..../NeededClass.php;)

Comment: Apparently it can work like this, but i need about 100 include !!! It's very strange that a big library like this can't work simple.

Comment: @Maypeur since PHP 5.3 is recommended use autoloaders instead include/require functions. Use composer (getcomposer.org) made this easy

Comment: I still think it too loud for developpement, i already have download the entire library why install composer ? Its juste a workaround it doesn't answer my problem.