# Zend Framework 2 Without Skeleton

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm newbie on Zend Framework 2 and i tried the CRUD application from the ZendFramework2 website. But my doubt is "is possible to use the zend framework 2 without the ZendSkeletonApplication?"

If possible, how do i include the framework in my applications?

Thanks!

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001205/how-to-use-zend-framework-2-class-in-my-project

Answer (score 0):

You can include individual components using Composer if that's all you need. But if you're trying to make a full stack ZF2 application, the skeleton is there to make your life easier.

Comment: Hello Tim Foutain! Thanks for the answer!
But how can I include these individual components using composer?
Should I do using git?